# DataGrid replaces first row instead of adding a new row,

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a Datagrid in my WPF that is populated with a by an ObservableCollection on a doubleclick form another DataGrid (users click on preferred title and details DataGrid is populated with the associated data).

Every time I search a new title, and then make a selection, the details DataGrid replaces the first row of data that was already there. How do I make it so that the DataGrid adds a new row so that I can log multiple entities at once for exporting?

My Code Bellow:

**DataGrid .cs**

```
// This action will seach the IMDb API for the associated infromation for the IMDBID that is tagged with the title you chose in the ListBox.
   private void Movie_List_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)      

     {  
        // Grabs the IMDBID associated to the movie title selected to be used with the second API request.
       // DataRowView row = (DataRowView)Movie_List.SelectedItems;


        string titleID = ((searchInfo)Movie_List.SelectedItem).imdbID;
        string newurl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=" + titleID + "&r=XML";

         // Prepares 2nd API URL request to get data for chosen title.
         // Creates a XML Document  to store the xml data that was sent back by the API.
        var doc = XElement.Load(newurl);

         // Creates a XML Noedlist to store the values that are going to be associated with the given attribute tag.
        IEnumerable<XElement> movieList = doc.Descendants("movie");
         // Creats an ObservableCollection for the Object Retrievalinfo to be displayed in the Movie_Datagrid, that can be edited.
        ObservableCollection<Retrievalinfo> gridInfo = new ObservableCollection<Retrievalinfo>(movieList.Select(movieElement =>
            new Retrievalinfo()
        {
            title = movieElement.Attribute("title").Value,
            actors = movieElement.Attribute("actors").Value.Split(',').ToList(),
            genre = movieElement.Attribute("genre").Value,
            rated = movieElement.Attribute("rated").Value,
            imdbRating = movieElement.Attribute("imdbRating").Value,
            released = movieElement.Attribute("released").Value,
            runtime = movieElement.Attribute("runtime").Value,
        }));
        Movie_DataGrid.ItemsSource = gridInfo;       
    }
```

**Retrievalinfo Class** (Object used for the ObservableCollection)

```
public class Retrievalinfo
{
    public Retrievalinfo()
    {
        actors = new List<string>();
    }

    //Creating a list of info objects that will store all returned data for selected title.
    public string title { get; set; }
    public List<string> actors { get; set; }
    public string genre { get; set; }
    public string rated { get; set; }
    public string imdbRating { get; set; }
    public string released { get; set; }
    public string runtime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DataGird XAML** (Movie_DataGrid, holds the details of the movie selected)

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Movie_DataGrid"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="292,107,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Height="214"
            Width="673"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding gridInfo}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Path=title}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Main Actor 1" Binding="{Binding Path=actors[0]}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Main Actor 2" Binding="{Binding Path=actors[1]}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Main Actor 3" Binding="{Binding Path=actors[2]}"/>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Digital Format" ItemsSource="{Binding digital}"/>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Physical Format" ItemsSource="{Binding physical}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Genre" Binding="{Binding Path=genre}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rated" Binding="{Binding Path=rated}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="IMDB Rating" Binding="{Binding Path=imdbRating}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Released" Binding="{Binding Path=released}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Runtime" Binding="{Binding Path=runtime}"/>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="File Type" ItemsSource="{Binding file_type}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before binding the Datagrid, You should get the existing items to a List and add the new Item to the List and then Bind to the Datagrid.

```
 List<Retrievalinfo> gridInfo = (List<Retrievalinfo>)Movie_DataGrid.ItemsSource;
```

Add the new Item to this List,

```
gridInfo.Add(new Retrievalinfo());
```

then bind the List to the datagrid,

```
 Movie_DataGrid.ItemsSource = gridInfo;
```

Comment: mainGridITMDataGrid is not recognized. And I cant find anything to resolve that issue

Comment: Please check the answer again!

Comment: Haha yah meant to comment and say I figured that out. Thanks

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Comment: When using this code, when ran I get an error saying Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[WpfApplication3.Retrievalinfo]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WpfApplication3.Retrievalinfo]'.

Comment: I even tried switching the Lists to ObservableCollection, but then movieInfo.Add adds a line with all null values

Comment: you need to fill the values,simple as that! this is just a sample to add new row

Comment: If I use your example it does not work because gridInfo is already declared as an ObservableCollection of Retrievalinfo, thus I can't make a list called gridInfo. If I change that name to another say, movieinfo, I get the previous error with not being able to convert ObservableCollection to a List

Comment: Have you heard of casting in c#>

Comment: yes but have not used it much. I know there's a big difference between cast and convert and most times I convert. How would you cast this?